# エラーが出てJavaScriptのコードが実行されない

Tags: javascript

javascriptについて質問です。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<title>javaスクリプト</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
body {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: skyblue;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.8s;
margin: 0 8px 8px 0;

}
.circle{
background:red;
border-radius: 50%;
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
</style>
<body>
<script>
'use strict' ;

const div=ducument.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('box');
div.addEventListener('click , function() { 　←ここが間違ってるみたい
div.classList.toggle('circle');
});


document.body.appendChild(div);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

という感じでドットインストールを見ながら作ったんですがドットインストールでは青い四角の図のようなものがでてくるんですが
自分のブラウザで開くと何も出てきません。そして開発者ツールで調べてみるとエラーが出ていて`SCRIPT1015: SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant`と書いてあります。
`div.addEventListener('click , function(); {` というところがさされていました。
どうゆうことなんでしょうか教えてください。

Comment: SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'ducument' is not definedというclickに'をつけてなかったので付けましたが今度は SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'ducument' is not definedというエラーが出ました　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　const div=ducument.createElement('div');というところだそうです

Answer (score 2):

`div.addEventListener('click , function() {`

に `'` が抜けています。

正しくは

`div.addEventListener('click' , function() {`

ではないでしょうか。

---

> Unterminated string constant

は「文字列がどこで終わっているのかわからない」といったような意味のエラーです。
ですので、`'`が抜けているのではないかと考えることができます。

**追記：**
質問者のコメントにある

> SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'ducument' is not defined

は つづりミスですね。ただしくは、`document`です。

ですので、

`div.addEventListener('click' , function() {`

と

`const div=document.createElement('div')`

と2箇所直す必要がありそうです。